# UITableViewCell selection style changing background color for all subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm writing in swift, using the storyboard, and I'm working with iOS 10.

I have a `UITableViewCell` composed of some subviews (they're `UIView`s). Some of those subviews have a background color.

The selection style on the cell is Default (gray).

When I tap the cell, the cell becomes gray. Good. However, the background color of each subview in the cell is also changed automatically to match the selection color (gray) of the cell. Not good.

How can I best prevent this behavior? I don't want the background colors of the subviews in the cell to change.

**NOTE:** I don't consider it a very good solution to do my own selection by listening for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method and then setting the background color of the cell's content view. Perhaps this is the only way, but I want to see if there are other options first.

**UPDATE:**
Just to clarify, another reason I don't like the above solution of listening for the delegate is that it fixes the issue per cell. So if I have other custom cells that use the same subviews, I would have to implement the same fix. I want something that fixes this at the view level, rather than the cell level. So that when I use those same views in other custom cells for different table views, I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Have you tried setting the background color of the subviews to something other than transparent in the story board?

Comment: @theMikeSwan They're not transparent in the storyboard. They have background colors. Red or green, etc.

Comment: Regarding your last update: You could subclass the TableViewController and override the delegate listener there. When your custom TableViewControllers are subclassed from this one you do not have to copy the logic

Answer (score 0):

This way is better than listening to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for sure.
Play with these properties in your custom cell class:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isSelected {
                //play with colors
                print("selected")
            } else {
                //play with colors
                print("deselected")
            }
        }
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted {
                //play with colors
                print("highlighted")
            } else {
                //play with colors
                print("not highlighted")
            }
        }
    }
```

Disable selection style:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

And tricky one:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
```

Comment: Hmmm...the problem is that I want to make this work no matter which custom cell I'm using. Other custom cells I have also use the same subviews, so I don't want to fix this per cell. Maybe there's a property on UIView that I can set to prevent the cell selection style from affecting that view's color?

Comment: This one: cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Comment: That's on the cell, not the subview. I want to fix this at the subview level so that when I use the subview in other cells, I don't have to worry about it. I want to be able to set the cell selection style, without affecting the color of the subviews.

Comment: I updated my answer and added the tricky method. It's what you want I hope :)

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's still fixing it at the cell level. So every custom cell that uses my subview would have to do this. I would rather fix it another way, at the subview level. But if there's no other way, this is a possible option I think.

Comment: "So that when I use those same views in other custom cells for different table views, I don't have to worry about it." - I think it's impossible.

Comment: @EthanG then make this cell as a base class and subclass it if a cell has to have this effect.

Comment: Yeah, I also think subclassing is a solution.